Why was my rate-limiting question closed for being opinion based?
What are some good Nginx rate limits for WordPress websites?
Nginx rate-limiting is opinionated? Is it sorta like asking people what their favorite color is, or who has the best pizza in Chicago?
Compare these allowed opinions:
https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com+%22good%22

Allowed opinions: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com+%22good%22

"What are some good nginx rate limits" is indeed opinionated. Also, the existence of other non-closed questions should not be taken as evidence that these questions are allowed. There's a significant backlog of unclosed questions, but this doesn't mean it's accepted

20+ year web developer here. Its opinion-based.

I think the answer box is a bit further down.

ServerFault said it's better for StackOverflow because it's not a problem that needs fixing. The use case is mentioned in the OP post.

Also, your google search doesn't actually find exclusively opinionated questions. The first hit on google for me is an on-topic C++ question about a stringstream function that happens to be named good. There's also plenty of ways to use "good" that has nothing to do with opinions, for example in the expression "all good", which also will be caught by your google search

@Zoe Thanks for pointing out the inconsistent treatment of my question being closed.

@BDL that's a common misconception and OP post mentions a typical WordPress site with low traffic, easy discussion to be had there.

For better or worse, meta-activity makes more users take a hard look at your posts in main. Particularly when you are asking about those posts. That will usually make it so that the posts will receive more votes (up/down/close/reopen). You've experienced more of all of those since posting these questions in meta.

By the same token, I'm sure your Google query will result in some of the linked posts receive more attention as well. I know I personally cast a couple of votes on posts that resulted of that google search.

@yivi The first close vote on this question is from more than a week ago. We can save time here and just name the people who are down voting all my activity and the same names will most definitely appear several times...

@JesseNickles "easy discussion to be had there" Maybe you can actually post it as a discussion?

Since several users here are telling you they think that closure is in fact fine... what does it matter when the first close vote was cast? Shouldn't you instead worry about the question is on-topic or not?

Because my point here is to identify the harassment against my account which so far, hasn't been achieved through any means.

@JesseNickles: What is "typical" or "low traffic"? Even if the question wouldn't be opinion based (which it imho isn't) and it would be on-topic (which it isn't) then, the answer doesn't even explain why the suggested values are good values, expect that they seem to work for your use case. You might be able to ask a valid question like "What does the value of limit_req mean in Wordpress?", but it's also more a server config problem that a programming one.

Because you are so far, proving the opposite. Saying "look at this off-topic question, it was closed!!!!", is less likely to be seen as proof of harassment than proof of users using their votes correctly.

You were already informed by a moderator on your previous Meta question that some of the serial downvoting against you has been reverted, that the remainder is still being actively investigated, and that SE is understaffed and may take some time to resolve this. I understand that you're impatient for a resolution, but bombarding Meta with angry questions about it isn't going to make the investigation go any faster.

@F1Krazy Well, I think it's useful to the community to publicly discuss things. If users can't block other users from harassing them, then having  the ability to anonymously harass others without end is just absurd imo. Either users should have more protection, or the platform should have more transparency... but mods just selectively editing and censoring things while harassment continues unabated is a very frustrating combination of features on this platform.

"Nginx rate-limiting is opinionated? Is it sorta like asking people what their favorite color is, or who has the best pizza in Chicago?" I mean, it should be self-evident that the answer is "yes". Different strokes for different folks. Different project requirements for different server configuration.

@VLAZ The exact point of my question is that this is a common misconception, rate-limiting is actually very misunderstood and there are rather common sense settings that would work well for the vast majority of low traffic WordPress servers.

The exact point of my question. I beg to differ, your question does not try to make that point. You’re introducing a lot of tangential things in the comments to support the continued argument - perhaps take a deep breath, step back, and edit the question body so it says what you actually want to say. Drawing that blood from the stone in comments isn’t fun for anyone.

Hm. I'm on the fence on this one. This is a "not a programming problem" question, it is not really opinion based. It just really, really reads like it, and nowadays that'll cause hip firing resulting in the wrong close reason being lazily applied. The flippant answer to your question is "the limit that works well". And I would argue that this is not an opinion, it can be factually answered in a non-flippant way at the very least by explaining what has zero chance to work and why. There is a valuable question in here. Just not for Stack Overflow.

I see two problems with this question:

It’s a server configuration question and not a programming problem.
It asks for opinions. What "good" is depends on the use case.

It might be possible to ask related questions like "What does the value of limit_req mean in WordPress?" although I'm not sure it this would be on-topic since it would still be a server configuration issue.
Please also note, that we expect for answers to show some kind of proof that they are correct. Currently, the only proof seems to be that the limits you picked work for your use case on your server. There is no real generalization on how to determine these numbers or an explanation on why you choose them.

I understand but I'm one of those "more questions should be allowed" believers, esp. now that Google has decided that Reddit and Stack Exchange are pretty much the only places on the internet where tech questions will rank. My understanding has always been that StackOverflow is the more "flexible" community on some of that. As mentioned, ServerFault already disallowed this question because it was not a problem that needed fixing and suggested moving it over to StackOverflow...

What SF believes and what's actually allowed here is not the same thing. We're a different site with different rules than SF - while SE is a connected network of sites, there's regularly misunderstandings between sites. That's also the reason why migration targets are limited. You were incorrectly informed by whoever sent you here from SF

@Zoe That's not really helpful, frankly. I'm getting at the underlying spirit of the platform here and not the intricacies of inter-community pedanticism.

This pedantry is what we call “rules”. That’s like saying it’s pedantic that you’re not allowed to pick up the ball in soccer, because you are in rugby. No, different things.

And definitely don't ask "What is best?" because that invariably leads to Conan.

Side note: Google does let some other stuff through. I got pointed to Expert's Exchange today. First time in about a decade.
